# getAllTests and getTestSuite in android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation

I've created a test runner extending android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner. I'm looking for a way to define the set of tests to get executed based on a set of configurations.

I thought I may be able to override the below methods to return my custom test suite, however, these are not getting called! Just wondering whats the use of these:

public TestSuite getAllTests ()
public TestSuite getTestSuite ()

Any clues? Any other alternatives I can use to define a custom test suite at runtime?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I also dont know... Another solution is to define your own annotation and annotate the test you want to run. Then you can run only the tests with that annotation using:

Filter test run to tests with given annotation: adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

If used with other options, the resulting test run will contain the union of the two options. e.g. "-e size large -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" will run only tests with both the LargeTest and "com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" annotations.

Filter test run to tests without given annotation: adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner